# How to listen when the microphone is muted on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, audio, microphone, appindicator

I'm developing an Ubuntu AppIndicator in Python that shows the microphone current status (muted / On).

I'm able to mute/unmute the microphone in my Python script, but I also need to listen to Linux event in order to update the Indicator icon when the microphone is muted outside my application (for example, in Ubuntu Sound settings).

I know I could poll the mic state, but I'd like to implement it in a passive / reactive way.

Is there a way to listen to "microphone muted" event on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to poll the state using pacmd:

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep muted
```

This is wrapped in a library called [pulsectl](https://pypi.org/project/pulsectl/) if you're using pulseaudio.

Comment: I was looking for a passive implementation. I want to just add a listener to some kind of Linux S.O. event and have my code called when something happens. But I have no idea of what kind of event I have to listen and where I have to register my listener.

Comment: Then you might want to look at pyudev.